# Swiftmailer prevent composer updates

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I have an issue with composer and Drupal 8.9.13. When I try to update Drupal, I always get the next error and I don't find a way to solve it:

```
#$> php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update drupal/core --with-dependencies

Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package drupal/swiftmailer (locked at 1.0.0-beta2, required as ^2.0) is satisfiable by drupal/swiftmailer[1.0.0-beta2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/swiftmailer 2.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/swiftmailer 2.0.0-beta1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/swiftmailer 2.0.0-alpha2
    - drupal/swiftmailer 2.0.0-alpha1 requires swiftmailer/swiftmailer ~6.1.3 -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.1.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.1.3
    - Conclusion: remove swiftmailer/swiftmailer v5.4.12
    - Installation request for drupal/swiftmailer ^2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/swiftmailer[2.x-dev, 2.0.0-alpha1, 2.0.0-alpha2, 2.0.0-beta1, 2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install swiftmailer/swiftmailer v5.4.12
    - drupal/swiftmailer 2.x-dev requires swiftmailer/swiftmailer ^6.1.3 -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[6.2.x-dev, v6.1.3, v6.2.0, v6.2.1, v6.2.2, v6.2.3, v6.2.4, v6.2.5, v6.2.6, v6.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[6.2.x-dev, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.0, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.1, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.2, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.3, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.4, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.5, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.6, v5.4.12].
    - Can only install one of: swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.2.7, v5.4.12].
    - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer (locked at v5.4.12) -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v5.4.12].
```

I have updated (manually) switfmailer to 2.0.0 version, and I have changed composer.json to lock it to 2.0.0. But It doesn't solve the issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: try to remove the vendor and composer.lock before

Comment: thanks, but It doesn't work. At the end, I had to remove the module and install it again and now it works.